# XMPP/Jabber on Django (chat server)

Tags: django, chat, xmpp

I'm looking to write a real time chat server in Django using XMPP/Jabber protocol (with mobile clients). Django will handle the user profile and inbox (non-real time part) through HTTP while the real time component should go through XMPP. I was wondering if anybody's had experience with this and could provide some tips, or if there is a better way to do this (Django + some other framework to handle XMPP maybe). Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you provide user profile from django to jabber server? i know that authentication can be done this way easily(i'm using ejabberd) but not sure about user profile, like avatars, display name, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Writing an XMPP server more-or-less from scratch is a task of love that will take you quite a bit more effort to get right than you expect right now.  Please look at [this list](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) to see if there's an existing project you could contribute to instead.